# Letter by letter animation with uitextfield when tap gesture executes is executing at same time

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextview

new to Stack Overflow and relatively new to swift. I'm trying to execute a letter by letter animation when the screen is tapped, but the letters appear scrambled when the screen is tapped multiple times.

I'm pretty sure that this is probably because the next line of text is animating at the same time the current line of text is animating, but I'm not sure as to how I would make sure that the current line is done animating before the next. What would be the proper way to do this?

```
   @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {



    if counter < textArray.count {
        storyTextView.text = textArray[counter] //
        storyTextView.animate(newText: storyTextView.text ?? textArray[counter], characterDelay: 0.1)
    counter += 1


    }
}

extension UITextView {

    func animate(newText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval) {

    DispatchQueue.main.sync {

        self.text = ""

        for (index, character) in newText.characters.enumerated() {

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                self.text?.append(character) // animation function is running at same time

                print("characterDelay \(characterDelay) index \(index)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If tapping while an animation is going on messes up the animation, why not just prevent tapping while an animation is going? It sounds like there's no coherent way to handle animating in the middle of an existing animation, so just don't do it in the first place.

Comment: What is the purpose of `DispatchQueue.main.sync`? That sounds like a really bad idea (nothing to do with your question, though).

Comment: @matt By prevent tapping do you mean not having the tap function call until the animation is complete or not having the user tap at all until the animation completes? And about the DispatchQueue.main.sync I found a similar stack overflow answer for this problem and they used DispatchQueue.main.async but I thought that maybe sync would prevent the animation from going twice. Sorry, I'm also new to threads

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when user taps the second time basically 2 animations start to happen at  the same time. Since you use 2 different texts as source and append character by character to create a new string you probably get interleaved string from it.

You are not specifying what a desired result would actually be when user taps the second time. The easiest would be to simply end the current animation and fill the whole current string. The hardest would be to animate both at the same time which I would not even want to go to deep on thinking about at the moment.

I believe in your case it would be better using a timer than a dispatch. You can create something like:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: characterDelay, repeats: true, block: {{ _ in
     // Append the character here
}})
```

It would also be better to deplete your string instead of indexing by doing something like:

```
let newText = oldText + String(textToAppend.remove(at: textToAppend.startIndex))
```

So this will remove the first character from source string and at the same time append it to the destination string.

Now to put it all together I would do the following:

```
protocol StringAnimatorDelegate: class {
    func stringAnimator(_ sender: StringAnimator, didUpdateStringTo string: String)
    func stringAnimator(_ sender: StringAnimator, didFinishWithString string: String)
}

class StringAnimator {

    var delegate: StringAnimatorDelegate?

    private(set) var text: String = ""
    private var timerWithString: (timer: Timer, stringToAppend: String)?

    func animateText(_ stringToAppend: String, intervalDuration: TimeInterval) {
        if let timerWithString = timerWithString {
            self.timerWithString = nil
            // We have a string already to append. Finish it
            timerWithString.timer.invalidate() // Stop the previous timer
            self.text = self.text + timerWithString.stringToAppend // Append whatever is left to append
            self.delegate?.stringAnimator(self, didFinishWithString: self.text)
        }

        // Create a new timer
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: intervalDuration, repeats: true) { timer in
            guard let string = self.timerWithString?.stringToAppend, string.count > 0 else {
                // String is either nil or depleted. Finish timer.
                self.timerWithString?.timer.invalidate()
                self.timerWithString = nil
                self.delegate?.stringAnimator(self, didFinishWithString: self.text)
                return
            }
            var depletingString = string // Make a mutable copy of string to deplete so we may modify it
            self.text = self.text + String(depletingString.remove(at: depletingString.startIndex)) // Modify both strings
            self.timerWithString = (timer, depletingString) // Assign new values
            self.delegate?.stringAnimator(self, didUpdateStringTo: self.text)
        }
        self.timerWithString = (timer, stringToAppend)
    }

}
```

This is now a whole system for animating the string. You can create an instance like:

```
let animator = StringAnimator()
animator.delegate = self
```

Then for instance on tap you simply call `animator.animateText(...` as you do now. And you extend your class to support a delegate to animator and on both methods simply update your text field or whatever text container you are using. Alternatively you can simply put this code into your class and use it directly as you seem to have been doing till now.